# Why would Nearest Neighbor Analysis give 0 observed mean distance?

Tags: qgis, nearest-neighbor

I am working with small datasets (around 100 points or less) with Nearest Neighbor Analysis in QGIS 2.8 (although I also tested in 2.6 and the result is the same). I have the layers referenced with a projected coordinate system.

When giving the results, I always get 0 as Observed Mean Distance, while Expected Mean Distance seems correct. I copy a typical output below:

```
Observed mean distance:0.0
Expected mean distance:367.212366515
Nearest neighbour index:0.0
N:98
Z-Score:-18.9384277177
```

Tested the same shapefile in other software and the value is valid (not 0).
Is there any known limitation for the input shapefile? Any workaround?

Comment: If you get an observed mean distance of 0, all your point locations will have to have at least two points.  Are the points duplicated in your dataset, or do they all have the same location?  I think you will need to show us your dataset.